# Same ID error when I try to replicate databases

Tags: mysql, backup, replication

I'm not able to replicate a database from a live server to local server(which is accessible from outside).

I got this error on master server

> Fatal error: The slave I/O thread stops because m
>   aster and slave have equal MySQL server ids; these ids must be
>   different for rep
>   lication to work (or the --replicate-same-server-id option must be
>   used on slave                                               but this
>   does not always make sense; please check the manual before using it).

On the master server when I type `SHOW SLAVE STATUS \G`

On Phpmyadmin I got this error:

> Slave IO Thread not running!

my master my.cnf file

```
[mysqld]
local-infile=0
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
user=mysql
# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0
server-id=1392211409
log-bin=mysql-bin
log-error=mysql-bin.err
binlog_do_db=vapes4you
binlog_format=ROW
[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

my slave file is

```
[mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
user=mysql
# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0
server-id=1392211002
master-host=********
master-user=vapesbackup
master-password=********
master-port=3306
replicate-do-db=dbname
master-connect-retry=60
[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

could anyone help me? thanks for reading

Comment: Did you stop and restart the server after changing the server ID?

Answer (score 4):

If command `show variables like 'server_id';` gives you different IDs, then it is possible that you entered it's own IP address, when setting up replication.

```
CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST = **'**192.168.1.155**'**, MASTER_USER = 'replicator', MASTER_PASSWORD = 'passwd', MASTER_LOG_FILE = 'mysql-bin.000002', MASTER_LOG_POS = 107;
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the slave server uses this my.cnf file?
Please run this command on both servers and compare IDs:

show variables like 'server_id';

Comment: sorry. Master: 1392211409 Slave: 1392211002

Comment: Are the slave and master on two different physical machines? Only thing I can think of is that you try to run slave process on the same server (which I don't know if this is possible at all).
Please try to give more details.

Comment: they are different machines. the master server is a virtual server bought from 123-reg with centos and plesk. the slave is a local server which is again a virtual machine. It is a centos with ispconfig3. The external IP for the slave server is accessible from outside. I don't know what information I can give you more? Thanks for helping.

Comment: on the slave server I got this error 'Could not execute Write_rows event on table vapes4you.log_visitor; Duplicate entry '67729' for key 'PRIMARY', Error_code: 1062; handler error HA_ERR_FOUND_DUPP_KEY; the event's master log mysql-bin.000001, end_log_pos 87421' and Slave SQL Thread not running!

Comment: First - running on mysql master "show slave status" will not give you anything, unless this master is a slave of another master.
Then - the error you have pasted here in your last comment, says that actually the replication took place, but stopped because of unresolvable problem - slave process is trying to insert a record, where a record with such id already exist in the slave db. 
You can do few things - stop slave, delete the record and start slave, then check the status. Other thing: you can scrap the slave, make a dump of master, restore it slave, apply "change master..." and start slave.

Answer (score 0):

Try Commenting out the server-id of SLAVE server while keeping the master intact. Then restart both.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was using a custom `my.cnf` file that was not being used to execut MySQL Server.

1. Press Windows Key + R;
2. Type %ProgramData%;
3. Search for MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0 or equivalent;
4. Update your `my.ini` file.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have to stop your slave by this command,

```
STOP SLAVE;
```

Then go to your master replica.

```
SHOW MASTER STATUS \G;
```

Then you will get the log file and the PID. Which you will need to add in slave. Go to your slave and then add this command.

```
CHANGE MASTER TO
MASTER_HOST=IP_ADDRESS,
MASTER_USER=USER_ID,
MASTER_PASSWORD=YOUR_PASSWORD,
MASTER_LOG_FILE=YOUR_LOG_FILE_NAME,
MASTER_LOG_POS=YOUR_PID;
```

Then start your slave.

```
START SLAVE;
```

I hope this will help to start your slave safely.